# Why does awk behave differently for $1 if the value is 0 (number zero)?

Tags: awk

When awk receives **"0"** as input, it behaves differently in some cases. Code below:

```
var=$1
echo ""; echo -n 'o/p of $1=$1 ==>'; echo $var | awk '$1=$1'
echo "";echo -n 'o/p of {$1=$1;print} ==>';echo $var | awk '{$1=$1;print}'
echo "";echo -n 'o/p of $1==$1 ==>';echo $var | awk '$1==$1'
echo "";echo -n 'o/p of {$1==$1;print} ==>';echo $var | awk '{$1==$1;print}'
```

The output with **"0" (number zero)**:

```
[root@host ~]# sh /tmp/te.sh 0

o/p of $1=$1 ==>
o/p of {$1=$1;print} ==>0

o/p of $1==$1 ==>0

o/p of {$1==$1;print} ==>0
[root@GORJALA ~]#
```

The output with **"1" (number one)**:

```
[root@host ~]# sh /tmp/te.sh 1

o/p of $1=$1 ==>1

o/p of {$1=$1;print} ==>1

o/p of $1==$1 ==>1

o/p of {$1==$1;print} ==>1
[root@host ~]#
```

Why is there a difference when I use `var=0; echo $var | awk '$1=$1'` and `var=1; echo $var | awk '$1=$1'`? All numbers are working fine other than `0`.

Versions:

- GNU bash, version 4.2.46
- GNU Awk 4.0.2
- coreutils-8.22-24.el7.x86_64

Comment: You example is using assignments (`=`) and comparisons (`==`) in the context of conditions (`CONDITION { action }`) and in the context of actions (`condition { ACTION }`) and showing comparisons of the behaviors of all combinations of that, even combinations that make no sense (e.g. `{$1==$1;print}`) but then your question is specifically just `Why there is a difference when I use var=0; echo $var | awk '$1=$1' and var=1; echo $var | awk '$1=$1'` so why include all that other stuff and get people explaining things that are irrelevant to your question?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [The GNU Awk User’s Guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Assignment-Ops.html):

> An assignment is an expression, so it has a value—the same value that
>   is assigned. Thus, ‘z = 1’ is an expression with the value one.

So

- `echo 0 | awk '$1=$1'` the pattern evaluates to 0 (FALSE)
- `echo 1 | awk '$1=$1'` the pattern evaluates to 1 (TRUE) and the default action `print` is executed

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106497/discussion-on-answer-by-steeldriver-why-does-awk-behave-differently-for-1-if-th).

Answer (score 7):

I don't think it is a matter of the numerical value: the standard conversions take care of that (here, at least).

The OP shows four different awk codes, all variations on: pattern { action }

**(a) $1 = $1**

That reassigns $1 to itself. It is not a boolean test, it is a no-op (effectively), and it returns the value of $1.  If $1 is a 0, the pattern is **false** and the default **print action is skipped completely**. If $1 is non-zero, the **input is printed**.

**(b) { $1 = $1; print; }**

That reassigns $1 to itself, also a no-op. In the absence of a pattern, the action is performed and the input is **always printed**.

**(c) $1 == $1**

That is a boolean expression that is **always true**. 0 is 0 and 1 is 1 (and aardvark is aardvark). In the absence of an action, the input is **always printed**.

**(d) { $1 == $1; print; }**

There is no pattern. The comparison evaluates to a true boolean which is discarded. The input is **always printed**.

Comment: Nit-pick: `$1 = $1` isn't a no-op. It'll cause awk to reconstruct `$0`, discarding leading/trailing blanks if the default `FS` is used, and replacing all `FS`s with `OFS`s.

Comment: @EdMorton Absolutely correct, and useful tool in the box sometimes. I said "effectively" to try to keep it simple, as in the posted example it made no difference.

Comment: You should not rely on `$1==$1` being true all the time, there are conditions with `nan` that **should not** be true, even if the numerical value on both sides is equal (and equal to `-nan`).

Answer (score 6):

The existing answers fail to explain why

```
echo 0 | awk '$0="0"'
echo 0 | awk '$0=substr($0,1)'
echo 0 | awk '$0=$0""'
```

will all print `0`, but

```
echo 0 | awk '$0'
echo 000 | awk '$0'
```

won't print anything, though in all the cases, the pattern expression evaluates to `0`.

How come `0` is true in one case and false in the other?

That's because the "field variables" (the result of the `$` operator) are treated as a **special case**, and (if possible) are automatically converted to *numeric strings*, which, if numerically equal to `0`, will be considered false when used in a boolean context:

> A string value shall be considered a *numeric string* if it comes from one of the following:
>
> 1. **Field variables**
> 2. Input from the `getline()` function
> 3. `FILENAME`
> 4. `ARGV` array elements
> 5. `ENVIRON` array elements
> 6. Array elements created by the `split()` function
> 7. A command line variable assignment
> 8. Variable assignment from another numeric string variable
>
> and [if it looks like a number, read the whole description [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html)]

Please also read the [`RATIONALE`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_18) for the reasons why the concept of numeric strings and this special-casing was needed, especially the bit about a comparison like `echo 0 000 | awk '$1==$2'` being true, but not `echo 0 | awk '$1=="000"'`.

---

As another quirk, notice that, at least in some implementations, `$0` (the current input record) loses its magical "numeric string" property if an assignment to a subfield causes it to be recomputed:

```
$ echo 0 | gawk '{$1=0} $0'
0
```

This does not seem to be covered by the standard, though it matches the behaviour of nawk/bwk the standard awk is based on (but not that of mawk).

Also, awk implementations are allowed to recognize `NAN`, `INF` and `INFINITY` in the input as the corresponding floating point numbers, though support for this is spotty and inconsistent. You may still be bitten by eg.

```
echo But his daughter named Nan | awk '$NF'
```

not printing anything in FreeBSD's awk (bwk, original-awk).

Comment: No, *in all the cases, the pattern expression evaluates to 0* ... no it doesn't. In the first three cases they evaluate to 1. An `awk '0'` will never print. An `awk '1'` will always print. Similarly, an `awk ' "" '` will never print (null) and an `awk ' "0" '` will always print (length("0") > 0).

Comment: The quote you need from the spec is: **When an expression is used in a Boolean context, if it has a numeric value, a value of zero shall be treated as false and any other value shall be treated as true. Otherwise, a string value of the null string shall be treated as false and any other value shall be treated as true.** `0` is false, but `"0"` is true.

Comment: Hmm, erasing your comments? In `awk '$1="0"'` the value comes from a section of program code (`"0"`), not a field variable. And `"0"` is an string, that string is being assigned to `$1` and the final value of the assignment is still `"0"`. In the Boolean context it is being evaluated, the boolean value of `"0"` is 1 and that is why the input is getting printed.

Comment: No. from your comment: **in FreeBSD's awk**, doesn't print anything (tested on FreeBSD 12) but busybox (the command you wrote) does print. So, is there is a bug in FreeBSD awk, then?

Comment: wrt `echo 0 | gawk '{$1=0} $0'` - just like unassigned variables, input data ($0, $1, etc.) is of type "strnum". When you assign to it it gets the type that is the result of that assignment. So if you do `$0=0` then $0 becomes a "number" and if you do `$0="0"` then $0 becomes a string. When you do `$1=0` then $1 becomes type "number" but as a side-effect $0 is reconstructed by **concatenating** the fields using OFS between them and concatenation is a string operation so the type of $0 becomes "string". So, yes, `$1=0` will change the type of $0 from a strnum to a string.

Comment: In the case of `echo 0 | gawk '{$1=0} $0'` the condition `$0` is true if `$0` is a non-zero number or a non-null string and `"0"` is a non-null string and so invokes the default action of printing $0.

Comment: wrt `all the cases, the pattern expression evaluates to 0` - no, sometimes it's `0` and sometimes its `"0"`. In the first 3 examples you provide it's `"0"` (i.e. a non-null string and so a true condition in this context) while in the next 2 it's `0` (i.e. a zero number and so a false condition in this context).

Comment: @EdMorton There's no concept of "strnum type" in the standard spec. Please do not introduce parasitic, nebulous concepts, they only server to confuse the point. In awk, a piece of data (not a variable!) can only have two types: string or numeric, and it cannot have both at the same time. The "numerical strings" described in the standard are actual _strings_ which are flagged specially, so they are converted to numbers when evaluated in a boolean context. In the examples from the beginning of my A, they're all the string `"0"`, except for the last, which is the _string_ `"000"`.

Comment: Nit-picking about how the strnum vs numeric vs string types are actually implemented is not useful in this discussion. How they behave to a user is what matters. You can learn about `strnum`, etc. in https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html and hopefully its use of the terms "strnum" and "type", and the availability of the "typeof()" (not "number_or_string_with_or_without_flags()") function will clear up your confusion over what I was referring to in my comments above. For example `echo 0` and `echo 000` when piped to `gawk '{print typeof($0)}'` will both output the type as `strnum`.

Comment: GNU awk implements a _superset_ of the awk language, it's not relevant here. Also, I'm not "nitpicking", I'm trying to keep the discussion to the spec, not expound on "my understanding" of the matter. Please do the same. If you think you can better define the common & historical behaviour of ALL awk implementations with your strtnum concept (instead of the current special casing mess), by all means, do it!

Comment: `strnum` is not my concept, it's the word that gawk conveniently uses for the type that is referred to elsewhere as "numeric string". Printing/referring to "strnum" is not a superset of the awk language, it's just a more convenient term. I'm not better defining the common and historical behavior of all awk implementations, I'm simply stating what that behavior is. And yes, you are very definitely nitpicking.

Comment: @mosvy About your: **can only have two types: string or numeric, and it cannot have both at the same time.** Yes, In Awk the value of a variable is both a number and an string and it is converted as needed. That is the reason for having CONVFMT for example. But more specific to your point: What is the output of: `echo 000 | awk '{print ($1=="000"), ($1==0)}'` ? Is it `1 1`, so, both tests are true, the same variable is both text and a number. Converted as needed.

Answer (score 3):

## simple cases

Lets simplify first.

What the code `awk '$1=$1'` does could be understood by printing the value of `$1=$1`. As well as what the code `awk '$1==$1'` does could be understood by printing its value. Both fall into the awk definition of:

```
pattern   { action }
```

If the action part is missing, the default action of `print` is executed. Thus, an `awk '1'` will print all input lines. An `awk '0'` will print none.

So, the value of $1=$1 and $1==$1 would be printed by this:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 0 1 | awk '{print $1=$1, $1==$1}'
0 1
1 1
```

Therefore, for an input of `0` a pattern of `$1=$1` will **not** print the input line. For `1` (and any other integer value) it will.

The `$1==$1` is simple: it is (almost<sup>**[a]**</sup>) always true.

The other options you present `awk '{...,print}'` will always print because there is no pattern, and the default is to execute the code inside the brace, and (unless there is a command to exit awk) the last action: `print` will always be executed.

Of the four different options you present, only when the input is `0` and the code is `awk '$1=$1'` the input will **not** be printed. Exactly what you've got.

## more complex

What seems to be in discussion is what this should do:

```
echo 0 | awk '$0="0"'      # true as "0" is a non-null string.
```

Has an string `"0"` assigned to the whole input (`$0`), the output of such assignment is also an string (`"0"`). An string having anything other than null means **true**. So, yes, that would print the input, but not because it is a number `0` but because it is an string `"0"`.

## When to convert

Variable values in awk have a dual type: number and string.

The value of a variable could be given explicitly in the written code, like

```
awk '{a=1234; b=1e-3; c="string"; d="1234"}'
```

Assignment to numeric values generate a numeric variable.
Assignment to an string inside quotes "..." generate an string variable.

So, c and d are strings and a and b are numbers (which could come from two conversions: integer (strtod) and float (strtof) ).

The problem starts when a variable receives "user input", as when a field is read by the first time. What a `echo 000 | awk '{print $1}'` should print:  `000` or `0` ? is it a numeric value `0` or an string `000` that happens to look like a number ?.

That is where conversion starts, conversion is required both to obtain a number from an string and to obtain an string (that could be compared) from a number. In general, only "user input" needs conversion, it is assumed that the code as written contains the correct type (either a=123 or a="123"). And conversions could be forced by adding zero (var+0) or by concatenating an (maybe empty) string (var"").

## trouble cases

<sup>**[a]**</sup>

1. A string is always equal to itself, no matter what.
2. A numeric value is always equal to itself except if it is **nan** (sometimes).

   Even if `$1` is a nan (`+inf -inf`, or `0*inf`, or some others) most awk implementations (nawk, mawk, original-awk and bsd awk) will claim that $1==$1 is true. That is against the IEEE754 spec, which requires that a NaN should not be equal to anything. So, that is an awk (most awk) bug. Except busybox awk that would not claim that `$1==$1` is true if $1 is`-nan`, I can not confirm that that is by design as I have not reviewed their source code.

   ```
   echo '-nan' | awk '$1==$1'
   ```

   So, it is true that the code above would take `$1==$1` as true but that might (shall) not be true in the future.
3. Conversion is needed.

   If what is being compared are two strings or two numbers, no conversion is needed.
   When the type is mixed, conversion must be performed.
   What is generally implemented is that if an string **looks** like a number (`"123"`) (called **strnum** in GNU awk) and comes from **external** input (form code values, no default conversion is performed) then it is converted to a number and `a==b` is performed numerically. Otherwise, the comparison is performed as strings.

So:

```
echo 0 | awk '$0="0"'
```

Is always an string (`"0"`) and the result is true.

But:

```
echo 0   | awk '$0'
echo 000 | awk '$0'
```

are both "external input" and **look like a number**, so both are converted to numbers, and as the value of `0` or `000` is the numerical `0`, the result of the pattern is **false** and both will not print.

**Except**, again that if the input value is a numeric `NaN` (yes, numeric) and the flaw in awk to not follow IEEE754 is corrected, then, this, which prints in many awk implementations:

```
echo '-nan' | awk '$0'
```

might stop printing.

Note that this happens in FreeBSD:

```
$ echo 'test -nan' | 
    original-awk '{print $2,($2==1),($2==0),$2+0,$2*0,($2==$2)}$2'
-nan 1 1 -nan -nan 1
```

A `-nan` is equal to 1 and equal to 0 and doesn't print `test`.

Answer (score 1):

Because $0 is the *whole record* (complete line), $1, $2, are *fields* (usually separated by whitespace) in it.

Answer (score -2):

if you wanna do `$1=$1` while also ensuring all combinations of zero and negative zero gets printed, then you can do

```
echo -0.0000 | mawk NF=NF
-0.0000

echo -0.0000 | mawk '($!_=$!_)~_'
-0.0000

echo 0000    | mawk '($!_=$!_)~_' 
0000
```

`NF=NF` is the better approach - it's succinct, easy to understand, unambiguous, lacks non-printing edge cases, and has no undesirable side effects, with the added bonus being you don't even need to quote it at the shell level.