# awk: print last N columns but with a different field separator

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have the following command with which I can change the field separator for an entire record

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_|-";OFS="::"} {$i=$i } 1'
DOWN::COMP::002::wget::001::6::2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885
```

But i only want the last seven columns i.e `2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885`

I can try to do that with

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"} {for(i=7;i<=NF;i++) printf $i"::"}'
6::2020-04-10-13::40::27::395533885::
```

But this will add an `::` at the end which I don't want.

So how can I do this using OFS for the last N columns?

**CONCLUSION FROM ANSWERS:**

I was looking if there is any possible way with OFS

The solutions i saw below are not using the OFS. So its not possible using OFS

So the alternate solution is either to use `sed` or `if` inside `awk` which i am already aware of

So OFS is useful only when we manually do it like below

```
 print $1,$3,$5
```

**Then the question is:**
So is there a away to generate print `print $1,$3,$5....` programitcally so that OFS is automatically used.

Comment: You two outputs shows that you either want the `-` in the date replaced by `::`, or you won't. Which is it? Also, `2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885` looks like _seven_ columns, not six, and `6::2020-04-10-13::40::27::395533885` is _five_.

Comment: Please make a little effort to tidy up your question. Do you really want the "__last six columns__" as in the text, or the last __7__, as in the first example? Or the last **NF-5** = 8 (13-5=8), as in the second example? Or was it that the last **5** (10-5), since you have changed the field definition)?

Comment: changed to seven. its not six

Answer (score 6):

In this particular case, it's probably simpler to use `cut` instead of `awk` and then `sed` to change the delimiter:

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | 
    cut -d_ -f6- | sed 's/_/::/g'
6::2020-04-10-13::40::27::395533885
```

I prefer this since getting the last N fields in awk requires a cumbersome `for` loop, while `cut` supports the `N-` format for "last N".

If you absolutely must use `awk`, you could try:

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | 
    awk -F"_" '{for(i=6;i<=NF-1;i++){printf "%s::",$i} print $NF}'
6::2020-04-10-13::40::27::395533885
```

Or, if you want to use `-` as a delimiter as well, try:

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | 
    awk -F"[-_]" '{for(i=6;i<=NF-1;i++){printf "%s::",$i} print $NF}'
6::2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885
```

Comment: Note that in the first script OP uses both `_` and `-` as a delimiter, whereas in the second one only `_` is used, not sure what is the desired output.

Comment: @user000001 hmm, true. I can only assume the desired output is what they want though.

Comment: @unxnut I rolled back your edit since it isn't clear what the OP wants (their desired output doesn't use `-` as a delimiter and anyway, your edit changed the input but didn't also edit the output to reflect your change. Please make sure to always update the output of a command if you edit it in an answer.

Answer (score 3):

With (GNU) `sed`:

```
echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | sed 's/_/::/6g'
DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6::2020-04-10-13::40::27::395533885
```

Please note `info sed` on this construct:

```
The 's' command can be followed by zero or more of the following FLAGS:

'g'

Apply the replacement to _all_ matches to the REGEXP, not just the first.

'NUMBER'

Only replace the NUMBERth match of the REGEXP. 

interaction in 's' command Note: the POSIX standard does not specify what should happen
when you mix the 'g' and NUMBER modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon
meaning across 'sed' implementations.  For GNU 'sed', the interaction is defined to be:
ignore matches before the NUMBERth, and then match and replace all matches from the NUMBERth on.
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm interpreting your question "How to do the output with `OFS`" as you want to perform a single `print`, with no arguments, and let `awk` insert the new field separator automatically between the fields.

To do this, you will have to rebuild `$0`, i.e. the current record.  You can do this easily by first setting `$0` to an empty string, and then assigning to the fields.

Since you empty the current record, you will have to store the data that will be put back into it in an array.

The following is an example of how this could be done:

```
echo 'DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885' |
awk -F '[-_]' '
        BEGIN { OFS = "::" }
        {
                nf = 0

                # save the last seven fields in "field"
                for (i = NF - 6; i <= NF; ++i)
                        field[++nf] = $i

                # clear record
                $0 = ""

                # reassign data into record
                for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
                        $i = field[i]

                # output record
                print
        }'
```

This code outputs

```
2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885
```

And it does this by storing the data that should be part of the output record in the array `field`, clearing the current record using `$0 = ""`, and then assigning the saved data to the record before printing.

Comment: For multiple lines of input, if the `nf` counter isn't reset, each line will be appended to the previous

Comment: @guest Yes, better safe than sorry. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a ternary operator to select the correct delimiter:

```
echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" | 
    awk 'BEGIN{FS="_|-"} {for(i=6;i<=NF;i++) printf $i (i < NF ? "::" : "\n")}'
```

Output:

```
6::2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885
```

Answer (score 2):

another `awk` alternative:

```
awk -F'[_-]' -v col=7 '{ 
    while (col-->0) { printf "%s%s", $(NF-col), (col? "::" : ORS) };
}' infile
```

adjust `col=N` with "*number of N last columns*" you want to print.

---

Answer to the revised question to:

> *So is there a away to generate print print $1,$3,$5.... programitcally so that OFS is automatically used*

personally and also technically there is no reason to limit yourself to using *OFS*, but well if you want, here is how to do it:

```
awk -F'[_-]' -v c=col=7 '{
    while (col-->0) { printf "%s%s", $(NF-col), (col? XXX : ORS) };
}' XXX='::' infile
```

but you know what is the behind `OFS`? replace all `XXX`s above with `OFS`; now remove `XXX='::'` and change `XXX` to just `"::"`; well so why stuck at using OFS then?

Comment: Using each field as the format argument to `printf` may fail if field contains `%`. E.g. `echo %c | awk '{printf $1}'`

Comment: @guest thank for pointing that. fixed.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ echo "DOWN_COMP_002_wget_001_6_2020-04-10-13_40_27_395533885" |
    awk -v n=7 -F'[_-]' -v OFS='::' 'NF>n{sub("([^_-]*[_-]){"NF-n"}","")} {$1=$1} 1'
2020::04::10::13::40::27::395533885
```

Comment: Readers take heed: this answer is using [interval expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Interval-Expressions) which are not yet supported in most awk implementations, except for GNU awk and busybox awk. As of April 2020, this does not work with the default awk from Debian, OpenBSD or FreeBSD.

Comment: Interval expressions are part of POSIX EREs and so are supported by most awks, including of course all POSIX awks and including /usr/xpg4/bin/awk on Solaris and the default OSX/BSD awk on MacOS. They've been part of gawk since version 3.0 was released about 20 years ago. If your awk doesn't support RE intervals then it's time to get a new awk.

Comment: You're missing my point. Using that feature with awk implementations which do not support it will result in SILENT data corruption, NOT in a syntax error. That's not something _I_ would foist upon unsuspecting users, just to make a point that they should update to my preferred version of awk.

Comment: And FYI, `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` on Solaris is NOT standard-compliant (or, more precisely, it's _too_ compliant with an obsolete, faulty version of the standard): with `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk`, `0=="000"` will evaluate to 1 -> TRUE, something that the current standard [explicitly forbids](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html#tag_20_06_18).  So IMHO, using `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of `/usr/bin/nawk` on Solaris is not a good idea.

Comment: I'm not missing your point, I'm addressing your point and MY point is simply that RE intervals have been an important part of EREs for 20+ years and you're better off with an awk that supports them than one where they are `not yet supported`. I didnt say anyone should use `my preferred version of awk`, I said they should update to an awk that supports RE intervals. I didnt say /usr/xpg4/bin/awk was POSIX compliant, I said it supported RE intervals in addition to POSIX compliant awks. If youre going to disagree with something I said then please select something I actually said to disagree with.

Comment: @mosvy I decided to google one of the awks you claim don't support RE intervals - the OpenBSD awk man page is at https://man.openbsd.org/awk.1 and it references the OpenBSD ERE man page at https://man.openbsd.org/re_format.7 which says `{n,m} {n,} {n}
    Matches the single character regular expression or subexpression immediately preceding it at least n and at most m times.`. The man page for FreeBSD awk refers to an ERE page which also describes RE intervals (but they call them `bound`s). I couldn't find a definitive statement of which is the default awk on Debian but gawk is available.

Comment: You should've decide to **TEST IT** instead of googling it. Interval expressions DO NOT WORK with the default awk from Debian 10 (Busty), OpenBSD 6.6 (and the current 6.7-snapshot) and FreeBSD 12.1. They also do not work with the `/usr/bin/nawk` from Solaris 11, which because `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` is badly broken, is the only usable awk on Solaris. Especially since your solution may result in __SILENT DATA CORRUPTION__, the warning from my first comment should've featured PROMINENTLY at the front of your answer.

Comment: Or you could've at least read the manpage you linked to up to its end and its [STANDARDS](https://man.openbsd.org/awk.1#STANDARDS) section.

Comment: Of course they don't work with nawk, I never suggested they did. I don't have access to 20 different awks to test with, nor the inclination to do so, nor is it necessary to post warnings on POSIX solutions that some tools aren't POSIX compliant nor that older versions of some tools that some people may have on their systems may not be. The only relevant advice is that if the awk you're using isn't POSIX compliant at a minimum then it's time for you to get a new awk and that again doesn't need to be repeated on every answer.

Comment: People reading this (not necessarily the author of the answer, who apparently doesn't care, anyways), may have a look at an [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/579666/308316) where I've tried to explain why bounds/interval expression in awk are a HORRIBLE idea in the first place.