# Use a Regex quantifier in Awk

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I'm having trouble using quantifier in a Awk Regex.

```
awk -F"|" -v col="$COUNTER" '$col ~ /doi\/tm-[a-z0-9]/ { print $col } ' OFS=, tmp.csv
```

This works fine, but I want to specify to the [a-z0-9] class a limit of 8 chars.

So I did :

```
awk -F"|" -v col="$COUNTER" '$col ~ /doi\/tm-[a-z0-9]{8}/ { print $col } ' OFS=, tmp.csv
```

It doesn't work, and :

```
awk -F"|" -v col="$COUNTER" '$col ~ /doi\/tm-[a-z0-9]\{8\}/ { print $col } ' OFS=, tmp.csv
```

doesn't work neither.

That's on a Ubuntu 20.04 system.

Comment: Which `awk` implementation are you using? What Unix are you running on?  Possibly related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/561772/bounds-in-awk-regular-expression-do-not-work-on-openbsd

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: I believe Ubuntu installs `mawk` by default which is not POSIX compliant and doesn't support regex interval operators (doesn't support POSIX character classes nor multibyte characters either). You can install `gawk` which should replace `mawk` with `gawk` for `awk`. Alternatively you could run `busybox awk` instead of `awk`.

Comment: Related: [How to specify regex quantifiers with mawk?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/506119)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, changing default awk to gawk solved the problem.

```
gawk -v col="$COUNTER" 'BEGIN{ FS = "|" } $col ~ /doi\/tm-[a-z0-9]{8}/ { print $col } 1' OFS=, tmp.csv
```

This works fine.